# May i know what does recursive=true means?

Tags: python, glob

```
for csvfiles in glob.glob('27-Jul/**/*.csv', recursive=True):
    print(csvfiles)
```

Hi, may I know what does `recursive=True` parameter means?

Answer (score 3):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html

> If *recursive* is true, the pattern “`**`” will match any files and **zero or more directories and subdirectories**. If the pattern is followed by an `os.sep`, only directories and subdirectories match.

So, the following files will match your pattern when `recursive` is true:

- `27-Jul/a/foo.csv`
- `27-Jul/c/d/baz.csv`
- `27-Jul/boo.csv`

If you use a single `*` instead of `**`, only `27-Jul/a/foo.csv` will match. `*` means “exactly one file or subdirectory,” and `**` means “zero or more directories or subdirectories.”

Comment: I'm still confuse about **. What does ** means anyway

Comment: @JianLong better?